# query returns a value, but ADODB.Recordset.fields("Value") = null

Tags: ms-access, null, wildcard, adodb, recordset

I am trying to collate data from two different servers, one SQL and one Access. I will admit my access SQL is a little shakey, but this one really doesn't make sense to me.

I am firing a query at the access database, I have configured queries in both servers to return single values for this function.

The query is as follows

```
Bookquery = 
"SELECT SUM(dbo_WIPJOBPOST.LQtyComplete) as [Sum]" & vbCr & _
"FROM dbo_WIPJOBPOST" & vbCr & _
"WHERE dbo_WIPJOBPOST.LMachine like '**" & Machno & "**'" & vbCr & _
"AND dbo_WIPJOBPOST.TrnDate between #" & Format(Stime, "dd-mmm-yyyy hh:mm:sss") & "# and #" & Format(Atime, "dd-mmm-yyyy hh:mm:sss") & "#" & vbCr & _
"or dbo_WIPJOBPOST.LWorkCentre like '**" & Machno & "**'" & vbCr & _
"AND dbo_WIPJOBPOST.TrnDate between #" & Format(Stime, "dd-mmm-yyyy hh:mm:sss") & "# and #" & Format(Atime, "dd-mmm-yyyy hh:mm:sss") & "#;"
```

When I run the query directly against the access database I get a number returned under column "Sum". However in the application I am calling it automatically using my function which puts the query with the database and the column heading we are interested in

Bstring = onerecord(Bookquery, "Access", "Sum")

```
Function onerecord(query As String, DB As String, Field As String)
'function to return single cell recordset

Dim Conn As ADODB.Connection
Dim Rec As ADODB.Recordset
Dim constring As String

constring = SelectDB(DB)

Set Conn = New ADODB.Connection
Set Rec = New ADODB.Recordset

'Open con string and run query
Conn.Open constring

Set Rec = Conn.Execute(query)

'Check records exist
If Not Rec.EOF Then

'return result
onerecord = Rec.Fields(Field)
Rec.Close

Else
MsgBox "No records"
Norecords = True
End If

' Clean up

If CBool(Conn.State And adStateOpen) Then Conn.Close
Set Conn = Nothing
Set Rec = Nothing

End Function
```

For some reason once the query and the field are placed in the line

> onerecord = Rec.Fields(Field)

the highlighted prompt returns null. I have tested the query as it prints in the one record function and it works, I definitely have the heading as sum, but for some reason it doesn't work.

I think it is something to do with the wildcards around Machno, as if I specify a distinct machine the onerecord code works, but with the wildcards it does not (I am working off of older databases and random spaces in machine names etc are common.)

Can anyone help me take the final steps with this? It feels so close!

Comment: I got to the bottom of this!
Using * as a wildcard will work in both text editors, however "*" or "**" will not work through the ADODB.Execute query function
"%" does work through the ADODB.Execute function 
whew! Took some time, but I got there

Comment: cant edit anymore for some reason. Its supposed to read ", however * or ** will not work"